# Add custom field in contact form

Tags: magento2, contact-form

I added some fields in the Magento contact form, but I have a problem with one field, which is a select type.

I try to display the label of the option on the mail but now the value is display....

Can we fix that ? (form.phtml)

```
<select name="query-select" id="query-select">
   <option disabled>Votre type de demande</option>
   <option value="demande-devis">Une demande de devis</option>
   <option value="delai-livraison">Un délai de livraison</option>
   <option value="retour-marchandise">Une demande de retour de marchandise</option>
   <option value="dispo-produit">La disponibilité des produits</option>
   <option value="ouverture-compte">Une ouverture de compte</option>
   <option value="sav">Une réclamation/SAV</option>
   <option value="suivi">Le suivi de ma commande</option>
   <option value="autre">Autre</option>
</select>
```

submitted_form.html

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Entreprise"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.company}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Type de demande"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.query-select}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<p><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For achieved this functinality

We need to create source model.

Dont used it inline in form

First create source model

```
    <?php
    namespace Custom\Module\Model\Config\Source;

    use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

    class Contact implements ArrayInterface
    {

        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            $loadedData = array();

            $loadedData[] = [
                        'label' => 'Une demande de devis',
                        'value' => 'demande-devis',
                    ];
            $loadedData[] = [
                        'label' => 'Un délai de livraison',
                        'value' => 'delai-livraison',
                    ];
            $loadedData[] = [
                        'label' => 'Une demande de retour de marchandise',
                        'value' => 'retour-marchandise',
                    ];

            return $loadedData;

        }

    }
```

Then add form phtml

```
    <?php      
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $contactOption = $objectManager->create('Custom\Module\Model\Config\Source\Contact')->toOptionArray();
    ?>
    <select name="query-select" id="query-select">
       <option disabled>Votre type de demande</option>
    <?php foreach($contactOption as $contact){ ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $contact['value'] ?>'><?php echo $contact['label']; ?></option>
    <?php }?> 
    </select>
```

Then update sendemail Function and following code

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $contactOption = $objectManager->create('Custom\Module\Model\Config\Source\Contact')->toOptionArray();

    foreach($contactOption as $contact){

            if(strtolower($contact['value']) == strtolower($post['query-select'])){

                $post['query-select'] = $contact['label'];
            }

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I try to understand but I don't know in which files I need to put this code ? I found for the  first and the second but not for the last to update the sendmail function.

Comment: In controller file if used default magento please override it.

Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post

Please check this file path.

Comment: Yeah, it's works ! And if I want to send the form contact on different mail address according to the condition of the select value, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.but with our custom code. Can you please mark as correct answer it will help other developer too.

Comment: Ok :) Which file I need to update ?